# If I only applied on one site when required to apply to two, will they look at my file?

Tags: application, postdocs

I noticed for a few postdoc positions, they want you to apply both on mathjobs AND on some external site. I applied on mathjobs, but didn't apply on some external site. Will they look at my file? The external site didn't request anything that wasn't uploaded to mathjobs - sometimes just a CV.

I should have paid attention more and I'm sure I don't have great chances at those places (I have applied to several other places) - but will they even look?

Edit: I am greatly ashamed by my egregious error and accept full responsibility for my mistake including having my file rightly thrown in the trash with extreme prejudice.

Comment: If the instructions were to apply at both, and you did not follow directions...

Comment: @JonCuster That's correct. I did not follow their directions. I am ashamed.

Comment: That seems an odd requirement. Usually it would mean apply on either, not both. Are you sure you interpret it correctly?

Comment: Seems odd, but I think they are more likely to look at the "other" site, which seems to be CMU specific rather than math jobs. Maybe you should contact CMU directly.

Comment: Conceivable that they let mathjobs be the repository of materials, and minimal requirements to apply to the university. Avoids dealing with data retention issues I suppose? But, follow up on the other bits to do. At the least be in contact to say it is really confusing to apply in two places for one job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, my experience tells the other story. I applied to school X on mathjobs without applying at the school's application site, and I didn't realize that until the department head of school X sent me an email last week and asked me if I'm still interested in their school, and reminded me to apply at their external site. It was already 2 months after the application deadline, though, I applied and they sent me an offer several days later.

So, if a school really wants you, it doesn't matter too much (although I wouldn't do it again, and this is probably the only school that I forgot to apply at an external site). Of course, you should make sure someone in the school knows you have applied for their position.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, this is because the university requires all official applications for its jobs be on the university's own site.  If you do not apply on the university's site, the department cannot consider your application by university rules.  It's possible the department has been able to set things up so that they can consider a late application on the university site.  If it's available, I consider you do that immediately.

Comment: It is most probably too late already. Short lists have been made and preliminary offers have been sent.

Comment: @markvs How do you know every open math postdoc has already had preliminary offers sent?

Comment: I know about my University and several.other Universities where I worked before. The procedure is the same everywhere. The selection starts in December and ends in the middle of January when informal offers are sent. If the offers are declined, there is an opening for an additional candidate. That happened exacly once in my 25 years at this University.

Comment: @markvs Wait, are you saying that in 25 years only one offer has been declined? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @user152468: The offer is sent to the top applicants first, if they reject, the offer is sent to the next group in the short list, Only one time in 25 years after two iterations we still had a position vacant. As a result we got an excellent postdoc who is now a well known mathematician.